# Photos in two folders

Tags: dropbox

I just want to be sure that if I delete photos in one folder that they will NOT be deleted from the second folder that they are in.

Comment: Have you tried it with a test photo that you don't care is deleted?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it to confirm. Deleting one photo **does not delete** a copy of the same photo in another folder.

If anything does happen and one of your photos gets deleted by mistake, Dropbox typically keeps file backups for [30 days](https://www.dropbox.com/help/security/file-backups).